# issues with javascript checkboxes issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

the following code just says `unexpected identifier;`

```
var icheckBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
            for(int i=0; i < icheckBoxes.length; i++) {
                if (!icheckBoxes[i].is(":checked")) { 
                    $('input[type="checkbox').addClass('has-error');    
                    AgreeIsActive = false;
                    $('#AgreementSubmit').prop('disabled', false);  
                   return;
                }
            }
```

Seems to be the `int` as the culprit but i tried it to change it to `var` but no success and got a different error:

`Uncaught TypeError: icheckBoxes[i].is is not a function`

Update#1

New Code added with the help

```
var icheckBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
            alert(icheckBoxes.length);
            for(var i=0; i < icheckBoxes.length; i++) {
                alert(i);
                //if (!icheckBoxes[i].is(":checked")) { 
                if(!icheckBoxes.eq(i).is(":checked")) { 
                    alert(i);
                    $('input[type="checkbox').addClass('has-error');    
                    AgreeIsActive = false;
                    $('#AgreementSubmit').prop('disabled', false);  
                   return;
                }
            }
```

it says the length is 4 and then it goes inside and it alerts 4 times 0 and the next alert which is inside the if condition, it just alerts it 1 time and that is also 0

Answer (score 2):

```
icheckBoxes[i].is(":checked")
```

should be

```
icheckBoxes.eq(i).is(":checked")
```

`[]` breaks the element out of the jQuery object and `is()` is a jQuery method.

Also as a side note, `$('input[type="checkbox')` is missing the `"]` on the end of it to make it a valid selector.

Comment: but will it work for multiple checkboxes to validate all checkboxes in one go

Comment: What do you mean?  Your logic is iterating over the checkboxes one at a time.

Comment: right but when i put some alerts, it just does not seems to be working, please check updated Code in my original Question

Comment: @Doel make sure to fix your selector I have mentioned at the bottom of my answer.